# How to get Start and End datetime SQL Server from table with Min Max Query, if multiple time in the same Item location

Tags: sql, sql-server, minmax

I have table in SQL Server, from GPS tracking:
[image: TABLESOURCE]

I Want to get start and date time like this:
[image: TABLE QUESTION]

If I'll try with Min Max Query, the result like this:

```
**WP_OBJECT STARTDATE   ENDDATE**
MEKARSARI   9/26/2017 12:05 9/26/2017 20:20
BABAKAN PARI    9/26/2017 14:20 9/26/2017 17:20
```

How should I do? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is a difference of row numbers:

```
select wp_object, min(wp_time) as startdate, max(wp_time) as enddate
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by wp_time) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by wp_object order by wp_time) as seqnum_o
      from t
     ) t
group by wp_object, (seqnum - seqnum_o)
order by min(wp_time);
```

To get an idea of how this works, run the subquery and stare at the `seqnum` columns.  You'll see how the difference defines the groups that you want.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, your answer it's usefull. But the results have too many start and end datetime rows every 2 minutes. If I want to make a simple row from the result, direct to last enddate time, how should I Do?

Comment: @Melvinsoft . . . I believe this answers the question that you asked.  This should produce three rows for the input you specified.  If so, the question is answered.  A new question should be asked as a question, not a comment.

Comment: Thanks so much Gordon... the question is currently answered.